# redisson-netty- invoked oom-killer

Tags: java, linux, redisson, oom

This is the oomkill log for linux
Aug 16 13:37:15 node-172020002225 kernel: redisson-netty- invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x6000c0(GFP_KERNEL), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=-997
Aug 16 13:37:15 node-172020002225 kernel:  oom_kill_process+0x219/0x310
Aug 16 13:37:15 node-172020002225 kernel: [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
Aug 16 13:37:15 node-172020002225 kernel: oom_reaper: reaped process 105600 (java), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
But at the time of the memory snapshot, there was one gigabyte of heap memory free, and a total of eight gigabytes of system memory and one gigabyte unused. Should not trigger oomkill。
Maybe it's Redisson's bug?

Maybe it's Redisson's bug?
The physical memory is 8GB in total, with 5GB allocated to the heap memory. At the time of the memory snapshot, there was still 1GB of free space in the heap memory, and the physical memory was fully utilized, occupying a total of 7GB.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.